# F# Map.ofArray issue with my code

Tags: function, f#

I'm an F# newbie and am having issues with my the code I am writing, for some reason the row split does not work and only a null array is returned by the Map.OfArray call.

code below:

```
let loaddata() =
       async {
            let! csv = sprintf "http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/trades.csv?symbol=bitstampUSD" |> fetch
            return
                [|
                    for row in csv.Split([|'\n'|], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) do
                        match row.Split([|','|]) with
                        | [|d; p; v |]-> ()
                        | _ -> ()
                |] |> Map.ofArray
            }
```

This is my fetch command:

```
let fetch (url:string) =
    async {
            let wp = new WebProxy()
            let request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url)
            let! resp = request.AsyncGetResponse()
            let ms= new MemoryStream()
            resp.GetResponseStream().CopyTo(ms)
            return (System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray()))
          }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to yield the matched values from your inner sequence comprehension. It's not clear what the format of the keys and values should be but you can do something like:

```
return
    [|
        for row in csv.Split([|'\n'|], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) do
            match row.Split([|','|]) with
            | [|d; p; v |]-> yield (d, p)
            | _ -> yield! [||]
    |] |> Map.ofArray
```

Comment: Note that you don't have to yield something in all code paths; `()` doesn't need to be replaced with `yield! [||]`, as both are essentially no-ops.

Comment: How do I also return v?

Comment: @user3623025 - You have to yield a pair, so it depends what you want the keys and values in your map to look like.

Comment: To build on @Lee's comment: if you want all free values to go into the map, you return something like `((d,p), v)` or `(d, (p,v))`, depending on what makes sense as a key. The first element of the tuple is used as the key, the second as the value.